C# crashes when two Python.NET calls take place simultaneously
My Blazor application is crashing when I run a function using the Python.NET methods, whilst another one is running. Here is the code in question:
try
{
    Runtime.PythonDLL = @"/usr/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so";
    
    if (!PythonEngine.IsInitialized)
    {
        PythonEngine.Initialize();
        var threadState = PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    await _js.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", e.Message);
    return;
}
    
using (Py.GIL())
{
    dynamic sys = Py.Import("sys");
    sys.path.append(@"/var/www/html/DBAdminTest/wwwroot/python/transform");
    
    var scope = Py.CreateScope();
    /*
    Python script and variable handling
    */
    try {
        scope.Exec(script, new PyDict());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await _js.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", ex.Message);
    }
    scope.Dispose();
}
PythonEngine.Shutdown();
await _js.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "shutdown");

The code above works great when I run a script on its own and even when I run it multiple times.
However, this causes an exception and the application crashes when I run the function while another instance of it is already running. This is the error message:
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
Unhandled exception in circuit '2PDfJXSqgTZikWfpUPVcLfrkGzen7ao5nbpp2VQBanY'.
System.InvalidOperationException: This property must be set before runtime is initialized
at Python.Runtime.Runtime.set_PythonDLL(String value)

I don't know what my mistake in the implementation of the code is, so I would be grateful if anyone could help out!
